# Рисунок со спрайта меняется!

Tags: html, css

Есть спрайт для сайта, при добавлении рисунка со спрайта, его вид меняется!
Рисунок со спрайта обведен красным. Почему линии на рисунке разной толщины, если это 1 и тот же рисунок?

[image: Меню сайта]

```css
.sfx-sprite {
 background-image: url('sfx-sprite.sprite.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
}
.sfx-sprite.common-divider-4x12 {
 width: 4px;
 height: 12px;
 background-position: -10px -732px;
}
```

```html
 <li class="header-menu-element"><a href="@Url.Action("Home", "Home")">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li class="sfx-sprite common-divider-4x12 mg-right-15 mg-left-15"></li>
  <li class="header-menu-element"><a href="@Url.Action("Company", "Company")">Company</a>
 </li>
```

Comment: Вы исключили проблемму с отображением на екране? На других устройствах так же выглядит?

Comment: На других устройствах не пробовал! Я уже когда то сталкивался с такой проблемой, но решил не разбираться, а тут вот опять вылезло! Ситуация была такая, что я рисунок линии в 1px или 2px (точно не помню) передвигал по горизонтали и толщина менялась!

Comment: Почему бы Вам просто на css не сделать это?

Comment: на css пробовал, но спрайтом попроще и быстрее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image Sprites(через который делался спрайт) криво прописал позицию и ширину. Когда сдвинул на 1px и увеличил- все стало нормально! Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего размер элемента отличается от размера иконки, поэтому кусок другой иконки становится видимым. В случае спрайтов размеры должны совпадать, а ещё желательно делать между иконками зазор хотя бы 1px, чтобы при масштабировании не возникало проблем.

UPDATE: Я понял, в чём заключался вопрос. Тогда проблема, вероятно, в том, что размеры блоков меню дробные и где-то получается полпикселя. В таком случае браузер округляет положение до целых пикселей и в некоторых местах картинка сползяет на пиксель. Делай зазоры межд иконками.

Comment: сам спрайт делался автоматом через Image Sprites из Web Extension Pack . Все размеры ставились автоматом, но почему в одном месте нормально в другом- нет!?

Comment: @SergeyBorshchov, `width: 4px;` - почему? Судя по картинке тебе надо `width: 1px`.

Comment: но там ведь 2 линии и 4px это ширина для 2 линий! И когда меняю ширину, то в одном месте стает нормально в другом- меняется!

Comment: @SergeyBorshchov, а. Я поняшл, в чём проблема. А то я сначала подумал, что должна быть одна линия. Обновил ответ.